# Counting instances of key value pairs in JSON file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working with a large dataset of objects with a number of attributes (see below) and trying to count the number of instances of each "type" attribute. The hard part is that there are a large # of different types, so I **can't start with a predefined list.**

So, the ideal output from the below data would be:

```
"Medic Response" : 2
"Aid Response" : 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Object

```
address: "9001 Lake City Way Ne"
datetime : "2011-02-12T18:04:00.000"
incident_number : "F110013072"
latitude :"47.693931"
longitude : "-122.30552"
type : "Medic Response"
```

Object

```
address : "97 S Main St"
datetime : "2011-02-16T18:46:00.000"
incident_number : "F110014403"
latitude : "47.600044"
longitude : "-122.334219"
type : "Aid Response"
```

Object

```
address : "509 3rd Av"
datetime : "2011-02-12T07:30:00.000"
incident_number : "F110012897"
latitude : "47.602114"
longitude : "-122.330809"
report_location :
type : "Medic Response"
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: will it be a flat array of objects or are we talking recursive?

Comment: @ste2425 It's flat I believe, thanks

Comment: `str.match(/"type":"[\w\s]+",/)` for non-formatted JSON, adjust for whitespace as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a key/value hash of type names/counts, and then iterate over your collection of objects, incrementing each count as you go. For example:

```
var counts = {};
var objects = [/*array of your objects*/];

objects.forEach(function (o) {
    // add the type to the hash if it is missing;
    // set initial count to 0
    if (!counts.hasOwnProperty(o.type)) {
        counts[o.type] = 0;
    }
    // increment the count based on the type
    counts[o.type] += 1;
});

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfectly. I had this same idea to store the Type:Count as key value pairs in a separate object, but wasn't familiar with the forEach or hasOwnProperty functions. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Yes it is very promising but you need to take into account that not all string values are allowed like "prototype", "__proto__", "constructor". If you may be sure not step on them the solution is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `array.reduce` to reduce your data array into an object map.

That is assuming its a flat array of objects and your not nesting things.

```
var count = data.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
  if (prev.hasOwnProperty(cur.type))
    prev[cur.type] += 1;
  else
    prev[cur.type] = 1;

  return prev;
}, {});
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/namq195g/)
[reduce docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` also:

```
objs.reduce(function(c, d){
  if (!c[d.type]) c[d.type] = 0;
  c[d.type]++;
  return c;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure that I understand your question  let consider the following inefficient straightforward implementation:

```
var data = [{address:"9001 Lake...", ..., type:"Medic Response"}, 
            {address:"...", ..., type:"Aid Response",
            ...,
            {address""...", ..., type:"Medic Response"}];
var i, j, b, result = [] ;
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i ++)
{
    b = false ;
    for(j = 0; j < result.length; j++)
       if(result[j].key == data.type) {
           result[j].count += 1 ;
           b = true ;
           break ;
       }
     if (!b) {
        result.push({key:data.type, count: 1});
     }
}
// result is the frequency array of the "type" values in data array
```